# PROC SQL: How to merge 3 columns into 1, and create an additional filtering column?

Tags: sql, sas, stack, multiple-columns, proc

I am trying to stack 3 columns into one, but however, I would like to keep a filter column to be able to distinct the variables, I have tried with Coalesce and Union all, but I don't get to understand how to do it, given that I do not have an ID column.

Here the tables:
[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data step approach.

I'm not typing out your data so here's a fully worked example that's similar to yours but not exactly the same.

Use `VNAME()` to get the variable name.
Use an array to get the values.

```
DATA wide; 
  input famid faminc96 faminc97 faminc98 ; 
CARDS; 
1 40000 40500 41000 
2 45000 45400 45800 
3 75000 76000 77000 
; 
RUN; 

DATA long1a;
  SET wide;
  *declare an array with the list of variables to transpose;
  ARRAY afaminc(96:98) faminc96 - faminc98 ;

  DO year = 96 to 98 ;
    faminc = afaminc(year);
    variable_name = vname(afaminc(year));
    OUTPUT;
  END;

  DROP faminc96 - faminc98 ;
RUN;
```

Wide to long using data step
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/reshaping-data-wide-to-long-using-a-data-step/

Arrays:
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-arrays/